# Test regression coefficient when overall regression has $R^2_{adj}<0?$

Tags: regression, hypothesis-testing, econometrics, regression-coefficients, negative-r-squared

I have recently read some work that features hypothesis testing of individual regression coefficients when the overall regressions featuring those coefficients have $R^2_{adj}<0$. One example is Schmidt & Fahlenbrach (2017), granted, in regressions where the primary variables of interest (the ones whose tests I am skeptical to believe) are instrumental variables.

The hypothesis tests of the individual regression coefficients turn out significant with $p<0.05$, for what it is worth. However, the $R^2_{adj}<0$ is troubling. If we take $$R^2_{adj} = 1 - \left[\left(\dfrac{\overset{n}{\underset{i=1}{\sum}}\left(
y_i - \hat y_i
\right)^2}{n - p - 1}\right) \middle/ \left(\dfrac{\overset{n}{\underset{i=1}{\sum}}\left(
y_i - \bar y
\right)^2}{n-1}\right)  \right]\text{,}$$ then $R^2_{adj}<0$ means that the fraction numerator exceeds the fraction denominator. That is, our (unbiased) estimate of the error variance is *worse* than our (unbiased) estimate of total variance. From this, I conclude that the model  exhibits "anti"-performance, and we are worse-off for having done the modeling. How could I possibly believe any individual regression coefficient hypothesis test when the model performs so poorly that we not only lack much predictive ability (rather typical) but do a worse job of predicting than we would do if we did no modeling?

How believable are the hypothesis tests of individual regression coefficients when the overall regressions have $R^2_{adj}<0?$

([This](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/561411/247274) seems related but not quite the same and containing a mixed-bag of responses, anyway.)

**REFERENCE**

[Schmidt, Cornelius, and Rüdiger Fahlenbrach. "Do exogenous changes in passive institutional ownership affect corporate governance and firm value?." Journal of Financial Economics 124.2 (2017): 285-306.](https://pdf.sciencedirectassets.com/271671/1-s2.0-S0304405X17X00056/1-s2.0-S0304405X17300053/Cornelius_Schmidt_Institutional_Ownership_2017.pdf?X-Amz-Security-Token=IQoJb3JpZ2luX2VjEN7%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2FwEaCXVzLWVhc3QtMSJHMEUCIDJooH%2B15SguzcG11zrCTuadE6ceDuIk4GcfNkRGS7xDAiEAupQwDu7PdtXZh%2B2R0Qf4zq36g5i6WeYTEHzLsOmTWOsqvAUIxv%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2FARAFGgwwNTkwMDM1NDY4NjUiDLB4B4AiVIHEtdjUWyqQBWLRxRIsw3V7bVAfp9i8569twnbcTJN0DPijiNKs0fi6CRs5qWd25lcNGFxEzDA6B24nZpMJ8fHAtcI4xrGUlGVKFpV1Ny%2Bol%2BDkgn2SdOsl53mXrRlhQhceOvBMGiZZCAFA2344V3A8JxjLs8HV39sbyg7j4JJNW1MPUHrdYM06VLvuBdu2ZesLTKPrCBcT0RbL%2FXOm%2FDTKFJp9T2egPvAzFK5y7Qe5BSUytEaxNN%2FGrhlTV084vqZnSFIOFDuGAibm5slXcjI%2F2K3XA8UGxX9ndXPfUwuwdaHeFxcAzsKu7NEie3iabKv0vgqCr6vJpx7FWZheItYabQ%2BL%2BKnFal%2B6sjNpWJucVzzff%2Fqqelej72t%2F0Hli7ybf5LHzI72Lw6ASQZ%2BWyWe%2Fhrw80jj%2FixDY0cfZrKkHdZg5HwEBQBnboonGdzUy%2BPaD9Jy93V6yg0ohnCYwGyBvNphgRdq1njuaClmZD%2FP3La27YFBs6wdxoaAHBOa5Zaf8%2FMtjv4ieBq%2Btdh%2FLNi%2F5tYg2LyveJcKndGDwtg%2BnZGAtawpNKzZHhgkAYhNlp9BP%2BOKhuLqwwLU0HpXaLbxkkptXjIjFZfBTsstBbWJ%2ByuGkDLZt9V%2FBekvdL3qRtUN1YwA4j4WONb9CVtIAxiBrRbvtIc2xcatEgcONthoxAdgOxEJj2cPRMDfRV%2FPoVHpkVkcSwYboMWadOiqVMhrrmN8GWn1L86WaUVxeMdxoBtHlUNszvIoGhf2vZ5TJqGww21u956hD%2Bdlrf8i9SRSrNJvAfLYNn3R2nvi%2BgAQ1jq0YjHuVn%2F5vK2fmr52GK%2BqgZ2A7KzUq1Jbsp4s08QRELylAKfaSsVZJ1YkIHjvKIbdAUylDhu9qMKC63KEGOrEB4Wmp3TllUt2ZtRJlcxDNN4oNm9p8rl%2BuimDFHeNZhtLEYtQ3csUwZnb7Y1CGDpMGM%2FRWhqIqjOuO5LLA4DR5ZT8R6bbnD7jrjv30JExzKumIGDvecYSIDHYDwqTR4YFOJ0UUaT0DzT3O5snlSLSqv20RBW0VDtkxQKC0LpwikF1fHgpmsoYNFgpxteCzOWdQD9A6DjvaKBVCEnr6fWK8QH4BHlGLNMQjGy06StsyM5CU&X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Date=20230412T215039Z&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Expires=300&X-Amz-Credential=ASIAQ3PHCVTY7Q6LLHSW%2F20230412%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Signature=1a101cebb609f713416eda7ea5863b1b88148f22301335fc0fcbe1e737bebc9d&hash=55181f63832c83fe16d0e7f6552be390c1698842a995520732446b3a9d21b16a&host=68042c943591013ac2b2430a89b270f6af2c76d8dfd086a07176afe7c76c2c61&pii=S0304405X17300053&tid=pdf-c4ea12fd-5936-41fc-b11d-5ba8690fe9e2&sid=027339f98dfd9542127ab5f38386e22c1a9bgxrqa&type=client)

Comment: I agree this is fishy.  If you're using adjusted $R^2$ and it's negative, then perforce you will conclude the *entire regression* is not significant and you (obviously!) wouldn't conduct further testing of the individual coefficients.  Do you have an explicit reference to that work?  It would be worth verifying the correctness of your account of what the author(s) have done.

Comment: Are there any interaction terms in the model?

Comment: @EdM I do not see interaction terms, no, though there is an instrumental variable approach. // I am not so sure that I agree with the final claim [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/421348/247274) that $R^2$ is meaningless.